# What file header data should be transferred during a copy?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm doing a byte for byte copy of a file on MacOS, and because of that I am losing all of the file header data about the file (i.e. LastModified, CreateDate, etc).

I don't want to use copyItemAtURL because it doesn't give me the fine grained control I need, specifically to allow cancelation of the copy, progress updates, ability to pause, etc.  But I DO want to mimic what copyItemAtURL does with file header data - I just don't know exactly what that is.

I know how to get the basics covered, grabbing the NSURLContentModificationDateKey, NSURLCreationDateKey from the source file, and applying it to the destination file.

My question is: what else should I be ensuring gets transferred from the original file to the new file?  Labels?  Security information?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I did find some general guidance about metadata in the apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH5-SW1%20Here) but it doesn't really call out which metadata should be populated under what conditions.

Comment: Files can have any number of attributes and other pieces of metadata, what "fined grained control" do you need?

Comment: I need to be able to pause/resume/cancel, update progress, etc byte for byte.  This is especially crucial for large files.

Answer (score 2):

This used to be supported by the [FSCopyObjectAsync](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSCopyObjectAsync) API in the old Carbon-based File Manager, which unfortunately is deprecated as of OS X 10.8 (aka Mountain Lion).

The documentation for FSCopyObjectAsync directs the reader to either [copyItemAtURL:toURL:error](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL%3atoURL%3aerror%3a) or the POSIX [copyfile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fcopyfile.3.html#//apple_ref/c/func/copyfile) function. The latter seems to offer the control you are looking for.

*Note: I don't have any personal familiarity with copyfile(); YMMV.*

Generally speaking, adopting the higher-level APIs, which are provided specifically in order to copy files, will be better than rolling your own using lower-level primitives. Not only will they considerably reduce the amount of code you have to write; they will also future-proof your application because anything that gets added to the file system in some future OS release will in all likelihood be automatically supported.

For the sake of completeness, here's an article (written pre-deprecation) that explains how to perform a [file-copy-with-progress-indicator](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/05/03/cocoa-tutorial-file-copy-with-progress-indicator/) using FSCopyObjectAsync.

Comment: Agreed, higher level is better if it does the job.  I've been using copyItemAtURL in the past, but it just doesn't seem reasonable for GB+ sized files which block and are not easily canceled.  FSCopyObjectAsync will totally work, but are not usable because they are deprecated and there is a restriction on deprecated code in the AppStore, as I understand it.  Copyfile() looks a little daunting...rock, meet hard place.